# How to increase shipping cost depending on quantity of order?

Tags: php, prestashop

Pretty much I want to increase the shipping cost depending on the number of items in order... e.g. by default shipping cost is 10$ but when number items goes beyond 20 it will add 3$ to shipping cost so it would be 13$

I tried changing codes but it's complicated somehow

I had to find all places that include shipping tax like in 1-blockcart module, 2-one page checkout, 3-payment, 4-inserting to database... And then change some codes. And it's a lot of work and hard

Comment: Shipping tax or cost? I think you meant cost but I want to be sure.

Comment: well yes actually shipping cost

Answer (score 1):

Prestashop includes a shipping range functionality. You can define shipping cost depending of the total weight of your products.

If you want a simple implementation, you can define all your products weight to 1Kg and add shipping cost ranges like those:

```
 0kg =>    20kg : 10$
20kg =>    40kg : 13$
40kg => 99999kg : 15$
```

Comment: well actually this is a good way and we might use it but still there's a problem and that is we want to increase cost when there is for example 20 different items.. and maybe a user buys 20 of just one item.. and this is still a problem

Comment: don't see why that would be a problem, if you define all your products to be 1kg, the delivery cost will go up regardless if you have 20 items of one product or of different products.

Comment: @VahidAbdi defuzed is right, if each products weight 1kg, it doesn't matter if you buy 20 potatoes or 20 different legumes the total weight will still be 20kgs.